# Dynamically Change Database with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have done quite a bit of searching on this to on avail.

I am creating a system that will ideally create a new database and tables upon user creation.

I am having trouble switching databases dynamically and then create a table.

```
        DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE " . $new_db_name);
        DB::connection('mysql')->setDatabaseName($new_db_name);
```

Creates the new table and I believe will changes database to, I confirm this by running

```
        echo DB::connection('mysql')->getDatabaseName();
```

But when I run the create table command the table is created in the old database.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using DB::connection('mysql') you're actually using your instance defined in your databases configuration file. That's your current connection to a specific database. Check [here](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) what I mean. That's why it doesn't work. You need to create it, add it to your config instance of your application, and then initalize it.

Now, in a succinct way, if I were you, I would make something like [this](http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly), where you will create a new database and add it to your configuration:

```
DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', array('schema' => $schemaName));
```

Then use migrations to create a new table on that database:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('database' => $databaseConnection, 'path' => 'app/database/tenants'));
```

After this, you should check the method used to call the instance of the newly created database:

```
App::make('config')->set('database.connections.'.$tenantName, $newConnection);
```